# Title column should not contain single quotation punctuation

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

column `title` should not have single quotation punctuation(`'`)

sqlite interpreter could not interpret this below query:

```
sqlite> .schema movie
CREATE TABLE movie (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, nth TEXT, for_video BOOLEAN
  );
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> SELECT title
   ...> FROM movie
   ...> WHERE title NOT LIKE '%\'%'
   ...> ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 1;
   ...>
```

---

How to check for single quotation punctuation? for both mysql and sqlite

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard uses two single quotes to escape a single quote in a string:

```
WHERE title NOT LIKE '%''%'
```